# The Web Browser show the correct values but when I use Jsoup the HTML doesn't have the values

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to get some values from a site but these values only appears when I use a Browser, like Mozilla. When I use the Jsoup I can get the HTML from the site but without values, only with the tags.

This is the site I'm trying to parse:

http://www.submarinoviagens.com.br/Passagens/selecionarvoo?Origem=nat&Destino=mia&Data=05/11/2012&Hora=&Origem=mia&Destino=nat&Data=09/11/2012&Hora=&NumADT=1&NumCHD=0&NumINF=0&SomenteDireto=0&Cia=&SelCabin=&utm_source=&utm_medium=&utm_campaign=&CPId=

I'm trying to get the values that appears inside these span tags:

If I access the previous URL from a web browser I can see the following values: '', 'R$ 2634,22' and 'R$ 2634,22', but when I use the following code the values disapears.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.submarinoviagens.com.br/Passagens/selecionarvoo?Origem=nat&Destino=mia&Data=05/11/2012&Hora=&Origem=mia&Destino=nat"+
            "&Data=09/11/2012&Hora=&NumADT=1&NumCHD=0&NumINF=0&SomenteDireto=0&Cia=&SelCabin=&utm_source=&utm_medium=&utm_campaign=&CPId=");
Document doc =  Jsoup.parse(url, 100000);
String title = doc.title(); 
System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

If I try to see the source code via Mozilla Firefox the values disapears too.
But If I use the firebug plugin I can see them.

Thank's for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The website uses JavaScript to populate all of the values you are trying to parse. You will have to use a library that can compute the javascript within the page. Not sure if there is one though.

anyone else?

Comment: Thank's, I'll try to find it!

Answer (score 0):

[Htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) is a headless browser that renders Javascript and should be able to present this page correctly.

Comment: Thank's his, I used the HTMLUnit and It worked. The problem was the javascript. So, I tell the HTMLUnit to waitForBackgroundJavascript and I can get the values now. But how can I force the Jsoup or Jericho to wait for the javascript. Can you use Jsoup or Jericho to do this, can't I?

Comment: Here is the code tha I used:
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000); 
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.submarinoviagens.com.br/Passagens/selecionarvoo?Origem=nat&Destino=mia&Data=05/11/2012&Hora=&Origem=mia&Destino=nat&Data=09/11/2012&Hora=&NumADT=1&NumCHD=0&NumINF=0&SomenteDireto=0&Cia=&SelCabin=&utm_source=&utm_medium=&utm_campaign=&CPId=");
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000);

Comment: I don't know about Jericho but Jsoup parses static HTML, i.e. the HTML that may be output by HtmlUnit after running the Javascript. But you can do the extraction with HtmlUnit, you don't need Jsoup then.